# File '*.swift' is part of module 'Module'; ignoring import

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, podspec

I am faced with warning that actually does nothing for me in this case, but is a bit anoying.

The project is combined with several subprojects via Cocoapods, so the structure is

- Root folder

  - Main project (that combines all the others and is used to deliver the build to the end-users. Imports Subproject 1, Subproject
    2, Core)
  - Subproject 1 (dependent on Core, imports it via Podfile)
  - Subproject 2 (dependent on Core, imports it via Podfile)
  - Core project (independent)
  - Module.podspec (describes subspecs, let's assume it declares the name of the framework - Module)

The development happens in Subproject 1/2, and to use some Core classes I need to `import Module` to the swift file. And it works fine. Because the development happens in the project directly and Cocoapods assembles Module.framework based on Podfile imports and Module.podspec

But when I am building the project from Main project - the Subproject 1/2 and Core are all in the Module.framework. Thus, the xCode displays warning:

> ⚠️ File 'FileFromOtherSubModule.swift' is part of module
>   'Module'; ignoring import

Is there any way to handle it? I haven't found such a warning in clang flags